# Search currently viewed email for a specific phrase, fetch a string to copy to clipboard

Tags: vba, string, outlook

I get assignments in emails that come to a shared Outlook mailbox.

In a typical email there are multiple strings and variables regarding a client, including their name, date and ID with a hyphen that I also want to get rid of.

There are two types of IDs. Both consist of 8 numbers and a hyphen, e.g. 1234567-8 and 123456-78. Sometimes there is a character in front of the number so I believe storing data in string is a must. I want to make several copies of the macro for each type of data. I want it all in a simple string form as I want to copy it to clipboard and paste elsewhere and have no need to process it further.

The code below does all I want except it stores the data in variables instead of string and does not remove the hyphen.

Code courtesy of vbaexpress' gmayor.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetCustomer()
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim dCust As DataObject
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim sCustomer As String
Dim bFound As Boolean
    On Error GoTo lbl_Exit
    Set olItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    With olItem
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(findText:="Customer #:[ 0-9]{2,}", MatchWildcards:=True)
                sCustomer = Trim(Split(oRng.Text, Chr(58))(1))
                bFound = True
                Set dCust = New DataObject
                dCust.SetText sCustomer
                dCust.PutInClipboard
                MsgBox "Customer number '" & sCustomer & "' copied to clipboard"
                Exit Do
            Loop
        End With
        If Not bFound Then MsgBox "Customer number not found"
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set dCust = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I want to search the currently previewed email (if that is possible), without actually opening it in another separate window, for a phrase like

```
"Customer ID:           123456-78"
```

and reformat the last part by simply removing the hyphen and disregarding the first part

```
"Customer ID:           "
```

(there is a giant space between the Customer ID and the number).

I also want to reformat the date from 11.22.2019 to 2019-22-11 and also copy it to clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searches based on wildcards are limited to what wildcards can provide, which is better than nothing, but still not very much.

Outlook uses Word functions for this, so that the [VBA documentation for Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute) applies. Applicable wildcards themselves are can be seen using the "Special" button in the "Find" dialog (F4 in Outlook), after "use wildcards" has been checked.

To my knowledge there is no concept of "optional" parts in wildcard searches, which means you need to try more than one wildcard pattern to cover your "sometimes there is a letter in front" case.

So the general approach, based this knowledge and on your sample code, would be

- Pick the currently selected `MailItem` in the `ActiveExplorer`
- For each predefined wildcard pattern

  - reset the search range to the whole email
  - execute wildcard search
  - as long as there are search hits

    - display result, let user pick or cancel the search

This way multiple patterns can be defined and you have a chance to continue to the next hit if the first hit is a false positive.

I found the pattern `[0-9-]{8;9}` plus `MatchWholeWord` to work reasonably well (blocks of digits and dashes, between 8 or 9 characters long), but real life data often has surprises. You will probably need to add more patterns. Watch out: for me, Outlook wants `;` instead of `,`. This might be dependent on the system locale, I'm not sure.

Also I'm not a fan of a "silent" `On Error Resume`. If there is an error, I prefer to see an error actual message. If there is a condition that can be checked in order to prevent an error, I prefer to check for this condition explicitly. This makes the code more robust and debugging easier. My `Sub` does not contain an `On Error` line for that reason.

In code, this would look like this:

```vb
Sub GetCustomer()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oRng As Object
    Dim sCustomer As String
    Dim patterns As Variant, pattern As Variant
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    ' bail out if the preconditions are not right
    If ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Not (TypeOf ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1) Is MailItem) Then Exit Sub

    Set olItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
    Set oRng = olItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range

    ' add more wildcard patterns in descending order of likelyhood
    patterns = Array("[0-9-]{8;9}", "[A-Z][0-9-]{8;9}")

    For Each pattern In patterns
        oRng.WholeStory
        While oRng.Find.Execute(findText:=pattern, MatchWildcards:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True)
            answer = MsgBox(oRng.Text, vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Customer Number")
            If answer = vbYes Then
              With New DataObject
                  .SetText oRng.Text
                  .PutInClipboard
              End With
              Exit For
            ElseIf answer = vbCancel Then
              Exit For
            End If
        Wend
    Next pattern
End Sub
```

Setting variables to `Nothing` at the end of the function is superfluous.